# Program Errors will not print part of code

Tags: java

Hello my program is giving me errors around the int pos = P.get(i);

it will compile and print the elements and the position of the elements but will not print the

pos val part of the code if you could help me figure out what part of the code is wrong and fix it

```
import java.util.*;

public class printlots {

//printlots procedure implementation

public static void printLots(List L, List P){


//display the table heading
System.out.println("pos\tval");
System.out.println("----------");

//repeat the loop for all positions in the list P
for(int i = 0; i < P.size();i++){

    //get current position from the list P
    int pos = P.get(i);
    //get the value (from the list L) stored at the current position
    int val = L.get(pos);
    //display the position and its corresponding value
    System.out.println(pos + "\t" + val);
}
}
//main method
public static void main(String[]args){
//create a list to store several elements
List L = new ArrayList();
//create several elements
List P = new ArrayList();
//add several elements to the list l

L.add(10);
L.add(20);
L.add(30);
L.add(40);
L.add(50);
L.add(60);
L.add(70);
L.add(80);
//add several positions to the list P

P.add(1);
P.add(3);
P.add(4);
P.add(6);

//print the values stored in the two list
System.out.println("Elements: " + L);
System.out.println("Positions: " + P);
System.out.println();
}


}
```

Comment: The error may be that you're not parametrizing List (`List<Integer>`), but please add more information. What is the error? What does your code do if anything? Does it compile (it should once you cast)?

Comment: Why would it print anything? You're not invoking your method. Voting to close as unreproducible/typo.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use [raw-types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html). And call your method.

```
List<Integer> L = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> P = new ArrayList<>();
// ...
printLots(L, P);
```

And change your method declaration to take the parameterized types like

```
public static void printLots(List<Integer> L, List<Integer> P){
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a call to printLots() method in a main() method

printLots(L, P);